# R: Subset returned is empty

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, subset

I've got a problem because if I make a subset out of a loop this subset has data. For example:

```
localGames <- subset(games, id_club_home == 1)
```

The subset has data

[image]

But, If I do the same inside a loop I've got the subset empty. This is my code:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(teams)){
  row <- teams[j,]
  print(paste(c("idTeam: ", row["idTeam"]), collapse = ""))
  homeGames <- subset(games, id_club_home == row["idTeam"])
  print(paste(c("Length: ", length(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
  print(paste(c("Total rows: ", nrow(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
}
```

I've got always 0 rows except by idTeam = 10. But total rows when idTeam = 10 is not correct.

```
[1] "idTeam: 1"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 2"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 3"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 4"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 5"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 6"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 7"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 8"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 9"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 10"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  57"
[1] "idTeam: 11"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 12"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 13"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
[1] "idTeam: 14"
[1] "Length:  10"
[1] "Total rows:  0"
```

The total rows of idTeam = id_club_home = 10 are 5 and not 57, like I can see:

[image]

We've got data in homeGames for all the idTeam's.

Why I get this result and not the correct result?

**Edit I:**

Here is all the data that I retrive from database

```
structure(list(idTeam = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14), teamName = c("NISSAN AL-Q\xc1ZERES EXTREMADURA", 
"CADI LA SEU", "CAMPUS PROMETE LF1", "EMBUTIDOS PAJARIEL BEMBIBRE PDM", 
"IDK GIPUZKOA", "LACTURALE ART ARASKI", "LOINTEK GERNIKA BIZKAIA", 
"MANN-FILTER", "MOVISTAR ESTUDIANTES", "PERFUMERIAS AVENIDA", 
"QUESOS EL PASTOR", "SNATT'S FEMENI SANT ADRIA", "SPAR CITYLIFT GIRONA", 
"STAR CENTER-UNI FERROL")), .Names = c("idTeam", "teamName"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(teams)
structure(list(idTeam = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14), teamName = c("NISSAN AL-Q\xc1ZERES EXTREMADURA", 
"CADI LA SEU", "CAMPUS PROMETE LF1", "EMBUTIDOS PAJARIEL BEMBIBRE PDM", 
"IDK GIPUZKOA", "LACTURALE ART ARASKI", "LOINTEK GERNIKA BIZKAIA", 
"MANN-FILTER", "MOVISTAR ESTUDIANTES", "PERFUMERIAS AVENIDA", 
"QUESOS EL PASTOR", "SNATT'S FEMENI SANT ADRIA", "SPAR CITYLIFT GIRONA", 
"STAR CENTER-UNI FERROL")), .Names = c("idTeam", "teamName"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(games)
structure(list(id = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 135, 
136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 
1), id_jornada = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 1), id_club_home = c(10, 
13, 7, 3, 14, 6, 5, 1, 2, 12, 7, 8, 4, 9, 10, 14, 6, 7, 5, 3, 
1, 2, 12, 11, 8, 4, 9, 13, 10, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 12, 11, 8, 4, 
9, 13, 14, 10, 7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 12, 11, 8, 4, 9, 13, 14, 6, 10), 
    id_club_visitor = c(9, 4, 12, 1, 8, 11, 2, 10, 3, 5, 11, 
    6, 14, 13, 13, 9, 4, 8, 11, 12, 2, 10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 14, 
    14, 13, 9, 4, 8, 11, 12, 10, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 14, 13, 
    9, 4, 8, 11, 10, 12, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 13), home_score = c(82, 
    71, 73, 55, 90, 63, 72, 52, 79, 59, 78, 79, 56, 71, 76, 73, 
    72, 68, 64, 80, 68, 48, 67, 80, 68, 77, 59, 72, 50, 53, 101, 
    58, 67, 83, 62, 48, 66, 72, 74, 57, 80, 78, 69, 89, 72, 68, 
    72, 59, 83, 50, 69, 85, 75, 74, 71, 73, 61), visitor_score = c(58, 
    53, 80, 83, 81, 54, 68, 83, 53, 64, 58, 55, 66, 84, 53, 63, 
    63, 75, 40, 81, 79, 64, 79, 73, 73, 78, 73, 54, 54, 88, 51, 
    64, 86, 72, 69, 91, 74, 59, 53, 68, 70, 74, 54, 82, 66, 62, 
    59, 76, 60, 88, 75, 79, 87, 52, 61, 62, 55), place = c("ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "PAB. MUNIC. \"JUAN SERRANO MACAYO\", C\xe1ceres (C\xe1ceres)", 
    "PALAU MUNICIPAL D\xb4ESPORTS, Seu d'Urgell, La (Lleida)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL MARINA BESOS, Sant Adri\xe0 de Bes\xf2s (Barcelona)", 
    "POL. MALOSTE, Gernika-Lumo (Vizcaya)", "PAB.POLDVO. EDUARDO LASTRADA (STADIUM CASABLANCA), Zaragoza (Zaragoza)", 
    "PABELLON BEMBIBRE ARENA, Bembibre (Le\xf3n)", "1018-ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL WURZBURG, Salamanca (Salamanca)", "PAV. MUNICIPAL  ESTEIRO, Ferrol (A Coru\xf1a)", 
    "POLIDEPORTIVO MENDIZORROTZA, Vitoria-Gasteiz (\xc1lava)", 
    "POL. MALOSTE, Gernika-Lumo (Vizcaya)", "POL. JOSE ANTONIO GASCA, Donostia-San Sebasti\xe1n (Guip\xfazcoa)", 
    "Palacio de los Deportes de La Rioja, Logro\xf1o (La Rioja)", 
    "PAB. MUNIC. \"JUAN SERRANO MACAYO\", C\xe1ceres (C\xe1ceres)", 
    "PALAU MUNICIPAL D\xb4ESPORTS, Seu d'Urgell, La (Lleida)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL MARINA BESOS, Sant Adri\xe0 de Bes\xf2s (Barcelona)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL ANGEL NIETO, Zamora (Zamora)", "PAB.POLDVO. EDUARDO LASTRADA (STADIUM CASABLANCA), Zaragoza (Zaragoza)", 
    "PABELLON BEMBIBRE ARENA, Bembibre (Le\xf3n)", "1018-ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "PAVELL\xd3N MUNICIPAL GIRONA FONTAJAU, Girona (Girona)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL WURZBURG, Salamanca (Salamanca)", "POLIDEPORTIVO MENDIZORROTZA, Vitoria-Gasteiz (\xc1lava)", 
    "POL. MALOSTE, Gernika-Lumo (Vizcaya)", "POL. JOSE ANTONIO GASCA, Donostia-San Sebasti\xe1n (Guip\xfazcoa)", 
    "Palacio de los Deportes de La Rioja, Logro\xf1o (La Rioja)", 
    "PAB. MUNIC. \"JUAN SERRANO MACAYO\", C\xe1ceres (C\xe1ceres)", 
    "PALAU MUNICIPAL D\xb4ESPORTS, Seu d'Urgell, La (Lleida)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL MARINA BESOS, Sant Adri\xe0 de Bes\xf2s (Barcelona)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL ANGEL NIETO, Zamora (Zamora)", "PAB.POLDVO. EDUARDO LASTRADA (STADIUM CASABLANCA), Zaragoza (Zaragoza)", 
    "PABELLON BEMBIBRE ARENA, Bembibre (Le\xf3n)", "1018-ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "PAVELL\xd3N MUNICIPAL GIRONA FONTAJAU, Girona (Girona)", 
    "PAV. MUNICIPAL  ESTEIRO, Ferrol (A Coru\xf1a)", "PABELLON MUNICIPAL WURZBURG, Salamanca (Salamanca)", 
    "POL. MALOSTE, Gernika-Lumo (Vizcaya)", "POL. JOSE ANTONIO GASCA, Donostia-San Sebasti\xe1n (Guip\xfazcoa)", 
    "Palacio de los Deportes de La Rioja, Logro\xf1o (La Rioja)", 
    "PAB. MUNIC. \"JUAN SERRANO MACAYO\", C\xe1ceres (C\xe1ceres)", 
    "PALAU MUNICIPAL D\xb4ESPORTS, Seu d'Urgell, La (Lleida)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL MARINA BESOS, Sant Adri\xe0 de Bes\xf2s (Barcelona)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL ANGEL NIETO, Zamora (Zamora)", "PAB.POLDVO. EDUARDO LASTRADA (STADIUM CASABLANCA), Zaragoza (Zaragoza)", 
    "PABELLON BEMBIBRE ARENA, Bembibre (Le\xf3n)", "1018-ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "PAVELL\xd3N MUNICIPAL GIRONA FONTAJAU, Girona (Girona)", 
    "PAV. MUNICIPAL  ESTEIRO, Ferrol (A Coru\xf1a)", "POLIDEPORTIVO MENDIZORROTZA, Vitoria-Gasteiz (\xc1lava)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL WURZBURG, Salamanca (Salamanca)"), fecha = c("2017-09-30 18:00:00", 
    "2017-09-30 13:15:00", "2017-09-30 20:15:00", "2017-09-30 11:00:00", 
    "2017-10-01 16:00:00", "2017-10-01 10:00:00", "2017-10-01 12:15:00", 
    "2017-10-04 20:30:00", "2017-10-04 21:00:00", "2017-10-04 20:30:00", 
    "2017-10-04 20:00:00", "2017-10-04 19:00:00", "2017-10-04 20:30:00", 
    "2017-10-04 20:30:00", "2017-10-08 13:00:00", "2017-10-07 19:00:00", 
    "2017-10-08 18:00:00", "2017-10-08 18:00:00", "2017-10-08 12:15:00", 
    "2017-10-08 18:00:00", "2017-10-08 12:00:00", "2017-10-14 19:45:00", 
    "2017-10-15 12:00:00", "2017-10-14 18:00:00", "2017-10-15 12:15:00", 
    "2017-10-14 18:15:00", "2017-10-13 20:30:00", "2017-10-14 19:00:00", 
    "2017-10-21 18:00:00", "2017-10-21 18:30:00", "2017-10-21 18:30:00", 
    "2017-10-21 18:00:00", "2017-10-21 19:00:00", "2017-10-20 20:45:00", 
    "2017-10-20 21:00:00", "2017-10-29 12:00:00", "2017-10-28 18:00:00", 
    "2017-10-29 12:15:00", "2017-10-28 18:15:00", "2017-10-27 20:30:00", 
    "2017-10-29 19:00:00", "2017-10-28 20:00:00", "2017-11-04 18:00:00", 
    "2017-11-04 20:00:00", "2017-11-04 18:00:00", "2017-11-05 18:00:00", 
    "2017-11-03 20:45:00", "2017-11-04 19:45:00", "2017-11-05 12:00:00", 
    "2017-11-19 12:30:00", "2017-11-19 18:00:00", "2017-11-19 18:15:00", 
    "2017-11-19 12:30:00", "2017-11-19 18:00:00", "2017-11-19 19:00:00", 
    "2017-11-18 19:00:00", "2017-09-28 20:30:00"), audience = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fecha_insert = c("2017-10-03 12:58:39", 
    "2017-10-03 12:58:47", "2017-10-03 12:58:55", "2017-10-03 13:03:03", 
    "2017-10-03 13:03:13", "2017-10-03 13:03:21", "2017-10-03 13:03:30", 
    "2017-10-04 23:23:07", "2017-10-04 23:23:13", "2017-10-04 23:23:19", 
    "2017-10-04 23:23:25", "2017-10-04 23:23:31", "2017-10-04 23:23:36", 
    "2017-10-04 23:23:42", "2017-10-08 20:57:09", "2017-10-08 20:57:14", 
    "2017-10-08 20:57:19", "2017-10-08 20:57:25", "2017-10-08 20:57:30", 
    "2017-10-08 20:57:36", "2017-10-08 20:57:42", "2017-10-15 16:30:27", 
    "2017-10-15 16:30:35", "2017-10-15 16:30:41", "2017-10-15 16:30:47", 
    "2017-10-15 16:30:53", "2017-10-15 16:30:59", "2017-10-15 16:31:06", 
    "2017-10-22 15:48:47", "2017-10-22 15:48:53", "2017-10-22 15:48:59", 
    "2017-10-22 15:49:05", "2017-10-22 15:49:11", "2017-10-22 15:49:17", 
    "2017-10-22 15:49:22", "2017-10-29 22:40:28", "2017-10-29 22:40:34", 
    "2017-10-29 22:40:39", "2017-10-29 22:40:45", "2017-10-29 22:40:51", 
    "2017-10-29 22:40:56", "2017-10-29 22:41:01", "2017-11-05 20:42:43", 
    "2017-11-05 20:42:49", "2017-11-05 20:42:55", "2017-11-05 20:43:01", 
    "2017-11-05 20:43:08", "2017-11-05 20:43:13", "2017-11-05 20:43:19", 
    "2017-11-19 21:17:57", "2017-11-19 21:18:06", "2017-11-19 21:18:15", 
    "2017-11-19 21:18:26", "2017-11-19 21:18:37", "2017-11-19 21:18:48", 
    "2017-11-19 21:18:59", "2017-10-03 12:57:48")), .Names = c("id", 
"id_jornada", "id_club_home", "id_club_visitor", "home_score", 
"visitor_score", "place", "fecha", "audience", "fecha_insert"
), row.names = c(NA, -57L), class = "data.frame")
```

And all my code ...

```
library(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), user='root', password='123456', dbname='estadisticas')
fileconn<-file("files/select-teams-liga-dia.sql","r")
sqlString<-readLines(fileconn)
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, sqlString)
teams <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
fileconn<-file("files/select-games-liga-dia.sql", "r")
sqlString<-readLines(fileconn)
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, sqlString)
games <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
fileconn <- file("files/select-boxscore-liga-dia.sql", "r")
sqlString <- readLines(fileconn)
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, sqlString)
boxScore <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
pointsScored <- vector("integer", length=nrow(teams))
pointsReceived <- vector("integer", length=nrow(teams))
for (j in 1:nrow(teams)){
  row <- teams[j,]
  print(paste(c("idTeam: ", row["idTeam"]), collapse = ""))
  homeGames <- subset(games, id_club_home == row["idTeam"])
  print(paste(c("Length: ", length(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
  print(paste(c("Total rows: ", nrow(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
}
```

**Edit II:**

If I run the code inside the loop line-by-line setting the value of j to 1. I've got a subset empty and I don't know why:

```
  j <- 1
  row <- teams[j,]
  print(paste(c("idTeam: ", row["idTeam"]), collapse = ""))
  homeGames <- subset(games, id_club_home == row["idTeam"])
  print(paste(c("Length: ", length(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
  print(paste(c("Total rows: ", nrow(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
```

The output that I've got from my code is ...

```
> j <- 1
> row <- teams[j,]
> print(paste(c("idTeam: ", row["idTeam"]), collapse = ""))
[1] "idTeam: 1"
> homeGames <- subset(games, id_club_home == row["idTeam"])
> print(paste(c("Length: ", length(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
[1] "Length:  10"
> print(paste(c("Total rows: ", nrow(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
[1] "Total rows:  0"
```

If we filter games by id_club_home = 1 we've got ...

[image]

And what I get is a subset empty :( If I create the subset with this code:

```
homeGames <- subset(games, id_club_home == 1)
```

homeGames has data!!! row["idTeam"] like we can see in the ouput of the code, returns 1. I don't understand anything :(

Why *homeGames <- subset(games, id_club_home == row["idTeam"])* returns an empty dataframe and *homeGames <- subset(games, id_club_home == 1)* returns a dataframe with data? :(

**Edit III:**

When I make the query to database I've got this warnings when I've got the data who are going to be saved in games dataframe:

```
Warning messages:
1: In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Unsigned INTEGER in col 0 imported as numeric
2: In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Unsigned INTEGER in col 1 imported as numeric
3: In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Unsigned INTEGER in col 2 imported as numeric
4: In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Unsigned INTEGER in col 3 imported as numeric
5: In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Unsigned INTEGER in col 4 imported as numeric
6: In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Unsigned INTEGER in col 5 imported as numeric
7: In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Unsigned INTEGER in col 8 imported as numeric
```

Is possible that this would be the problem? How can I fix it?

**Edit IV:**

Sorry, but I'm gonna get crazy with this bug ... If I change the setting of j to 10 ... We've got data!!! But these are not correct!!!

My code:

```
  j <- 10
  row <- teams[j,]
  print(paste(c("idTeam: ", row[["idTeam"]]), collapse = ""))
  homeGames <- subset(games, id_club_home == row["idTeam"])
  print(paste(c("Length: ", length(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
  print(paste(c("Total rows: ", nrow(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
```

The output of my code:

```
> j <- 10
> row <- teams[j,]
> print(paste(c("idTeam: ", row[["idTeam"]]), collapse = ""))
[1] "idTeam: 10"
> homeGames <- subset(games, id_club_home == row["idTeam"])
> #awayGames <- subset(games, id_club_visitor == row["idTeam"])
>   print(paste(c("Length: ", length(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
[1] "Length:  10"
> print(paste(c("Total rows: ", nrow(homeGames)), collapse = " "))
[1] "Total rows:  57"
```

If we make a dump from games we've got ...

dput(homeGames)

```
structure(list(id = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 135, 
136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 
1), id_jornada = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 1), id_club_home = c(10, 
13, 7, 3, 14, 6, 5, 1, 2, 12, 7, 8, 4, 9, 10, 14, 6, 7, 5, 3, 
1, 2, 12, 11, 8, 4, 9, 13, 10, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 12, 11, 8, 4, 
9, 13, 14, 10, 7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 12, 11, 8, 4, 9, 13, 14, 6, 10), 
    id_club_visitor = c(9, 4, 12, 1, 8, 11, 2, 10, 3, 5, 11, 
    6, 14, 13, 13, 9, 4, 8, 11, 12, 2, 10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 14, 
    14, 13, 9, 4, 8, 11, 12, 10, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 14, 13, 
    9, 4, 8, 11, 10, 12, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 13), home_score = c(82, 
    71, 73, 55, 90, 63, 72, 52, 79, 59, 78, 79, 56, 71, 76, 73, 
    72, 68, 64, 80, 68, 48, 67, 80, 68, 77, 59, 72, 50, 53, 101, 
    58, 67, 83, 62, 48, 66, 72, 74, 57, 80, 78, 69, 89, 72, 68, 
    72, 59, 83, 50, 69, 85, 75, 74, 71, 73, 61), visitor_score = c(58, 
    53, 80, 83, 81, 54, 68, 83, 53, 64, 58, 55, 66, 84, 53, 63, 
    63, 75, 40, 81, 79, 64, 79, 73, 73, 78, 73, 54, 54, 88, 51, 
    64, 86, 72, 69, 91, 74, 59, 53, 68, 70, 74, 54, 82, 66, 62, 
    59, 76, 60, 88, 75, 79, 87, 52, 61, 62, 55), place = c("ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", "ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "PAB. MUNIC. \"JUAN SERRANO MACAYO\", C\xe1ceres (C\xe1ceres)", 
    "PALAU MUNICIPAL D\xb4ESPORTS, Seu d'Urgell, La (Lleida)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL MARINA BESOS, Sant Adri\xe0 de Bes\xf2s (Barcelona)", 
    "POL. MALOSTE, Gernika-Lumo (Vizcaya)", "PAB.POLDVO. EDUARDO LASTRADA (STADIUM CASABLANCA), Zaragoza (Zaragoza)", 
    "PABELLON BEMBIBRE ARENA, Bembibre (Le\xf3n)", "1018-ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL WURZBURG, Salamanca (Salamanca)", "PAV. MUNICIPAL  ESTEIRO, Ferrol (A Coru\xf1a)", 
    "POLIDEPORTIVO MENDIZORROTZA, Vitoria-Gasteiz (\xc1lava)", 
    "POL. MALOSTE, Gernika-Lumo (Vizcaya)", "POL. JOSE ANTONIO GASCA, Donostia-San Sebasti\xe1n (Guip\xfazcoa)", 
    "Palacio de los Deportes de La Rioja, Logro\xf1o (La Rioja)", 
    "PAB. MUNIC. \"JUAN SERRANO MACAYO\", C\xe1ceres (C\xe1ceres)", 
    "PALAU MUNICIPAL D\xb4ESPORTS, Seu d'Urgell, La (Lleida)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL MARINA BESOS, Sant Adri\xe0 de Bes\xf2s (Barcelona)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL ANGEL NIETO, Zamora (Zamora)", "PAB.POLDVO. EDUARDO LASTRADA (STADIUM CASABLANCA), Zaragoza (Zaragoza)", 
    "PABELLON BEMBIBRE ARENA, Bembibre (Le\xf3n)", "1018-ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "PAVELL\xd3N MUNICIPAL GIRONA FONTAJAU, Girona (Girona)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL WURZBURG, Salamanca (Salamanca)", "POLIDEPORTIVO MENDIZORROTZA, Vitoria-Gasteiz (\xc1lava)", 
    "POL. MALOSTE, Gernika-Lumo (Vizcaya)", "POL. JOSE ANTONIO GASCA, Donostia-San Sebasti\xe1n (Guip\xfazcoa)", 
    "Palacio de los Deportes de La Rioja, Logro\xf1o (La Rioja)", 
    "PAB. MUNIC. \"JUAN SERRANO MACAYO\", C\xe1ceres (C\xe1ceres)", 
    "PALAU MUNICIPAL D\xb4ESPORTS, Seu d'Urgell, La (Lleida)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL MARINA BESOS, Sant Adri\xe0 de Bes\xf2s (Barcelona)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL ANGEL NIETO, Zamora (Zamora)", "PAB.POLDVO. EDUARDO LASTRADA (STADIUM CASABLANCA), Zaragoza (Zaragoza)", 
    "PABELLON BEMBIBRE ARENA, Bembibre (Le\xf3n)", "1018-ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "PAVELL\xd3N MUNICIPAL GIRONA FONTAJAU, Girona (Girona)", 
    "PAV. MUNICIPAL  ESTEIRO, Ferrol (A Coru\xf1a)", "PABELLON MUNICIPAL WURZBURG, Salamanca (Salamanca)", 
    "POL. MALOSTE, Gernika-Lumo (Vizcaya)", "POL. JOSE ANTONIO GASCA, Donostia-San Sebasti\xe1n (Guip\xfazcoa)", 
    "Palacio de los Deportes de La Rioja, Logro\xf1o (La Rioja)", 
    "PAB. MUNIC. \"JUAN SERRANO MACAYO\", C\xe1ceres (C\xe1ceres)", 
    "PALAU MUNICIPAL D\xb4ESPORTS, Seu d'Urgell, La (Lleida)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL MARINA BESOS, Sant Adri\xe0 de Bes\xf2s (Barcelona)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL ANGEL NIETO, Zamora (Zamora)", "PAB.POLDVO. EDUARDO LASTRADA (STADIUM CASABLANCA), Zaragoza (Zaragoza)", 
    "PABELLON BEMBIBRE ARENA, Bembibre (Le\xf3n)", "1018-ANTONIO MAGARI\xd1OS, PABELLON, Madrid (Madrid)", 
    "PAVELL\xd3N MUNICIPAL GIRONA FONTAJAU, Girona (Girona)", 
    "PAV. MUNICIPAL  ESTEIRO, Ferrol (A Coru\xf1a)", "POLIDEPORTIVO MENDIZORROTZA, Vitoria-Gasteiz (\xc1lava)", 
    "PABELLON MUNICIPAL WURZBURG, Salamanca (Salamanca)"), fecha = c("2017-09-30 18:00:00", 
    "2017-09-30 13:15:00", "2017-09-30 20:15:00", "2017-09-30 11:00:00", 
    "2017-10-01 16:00:00", "2017-10-01 10:00:00", "2017-10-01 12:15:00", 
    "2017-10-04 20:30:00", "2017-10-04 21:00:00", "2017-10-04 20:30:00", 
    "2017-10-04 20:00:00", "2017-10-04 19:00:00", "2017-10-04 20:30:00", 
    "2017-10-04 20:30:00", "2017-10-08 13:00:00", "2017-10-07 19:00:00", 
    "2017-10-08 18:00:00", "2017-10-08 18:00:00", "2017-10-08 12:15:00", 
    "2017-10-08 18:00:00", "2017-10-08 12:00:00", "2017-10-14 19:45:00", 
    "2017-10-15 12:00:00", "2017-10-14 18:00:00", "2017-10-15 12:15:00", 
    "2017-10-14 18:15:00", "2017-10-13 20:30:00", "2017-10-14 19:00:00", 
    "2017-10-21 18:00:00", "2017-10-21 18:30:00", "2017-10-21 18:30:00", 
    "2017-10-21 18:00:00", "2017-10-21 19:00:00", "2017-10-20 20:45:00", 
    "2017-10-20 21:00:00", "2017-10-29 12:00:00", "2017-10-28 18:00:00", 
    "2017-10-29 12:15:00", "2017-10-28 18:15:00", "2017-10-27 20:30:00", 
    "2017-10-29 19:00:00", "2017-10-28 20:00:00", "2017-11-04 18:00:00", 
    "2017-11-04 20:00:00", "2017-11-04 18:00:00", "2017-11-05 18:00:00", 
    "2017-11-03 20:45:00", "2017-11-04 19:45:00", "2017-11-05 12:00:00", 
    "2017-11-19 12:30:00", "2017-11-19 18:00:00", "2017-11-19 18:15:00", 
    "2017-11-19 12:30:00", "2017-11-19 18:00:00", "2017-11-19 19:00:00", 
    "2017-11-18 19:00:00", "2017-09-28 20:30:00"), audience = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fecha_insert = c("2017-10-03 12:58:39", 
    "2017-10-03 12:58:47", "2017-10-03 12:58:55", "2017-10-03 13:03:03", 
    "2017-10-03 13:03:13", "2017-10-03 13:03:21", "2017-10-03 13:03:30", 
    "2017-10-04 23:23:07", "2017-10-04 23:23:13", "2017-10-04 23:23:19", 
    "2017-10-04 23:23:25", "2017-10-04 23:23:31", "2017-10-04 23:23:36", 
    "2017-10-04 23:23:42", "2017-10-08 20:57:09", "2017-10-08 20:57:14", 
    "2017-10-08 20:57:19", "2017-10-08 20:57:25", "2017-10-08 20:57:30", 
    "2017-10-08 20:57:36", "2017-10-08 20:57:42", "2017-10-15 16:30:27", 
    "2017-10-15 16:30:35", "2017-10-15 16:30:41", "2017-10-15 16:30:47", 
    "2017-10-15 16:30:53", "2017-10-15 16:30:59", "2017-10-15 16:31:06", 
    "2017-10-22 15:48:47", "2017-10-22 15:48:53", "2017-10-22 15:48:59", 
    "2017-10-22 15:49:05", "2017-10-22 15:49:11", "2017-10-22 15:49:17", 
    "2017-10-22 15:49:22", "2017-10-29 22:40:28", "2017-10-29 22:40:34", 
    "2017-10-29 22:40:39", "2017-10-29 22:40:45", "2017-10-29 22:40:51", 
    "2017-10-29 22:40:56", "2017-10-29 22:41:01", "2017-11-05 20:42:43", 
    "2017-11-05 20:42:49", "2017-11-05 20:42:55", "2017-11-05 20:43:01", 
    "2017-11-05 20:43:08", "2017-11-05 20:43:13", "2017-11-05 20:43:19", 
    "2017-11-19 21:17:57", "2017-11-19 21:18:06", "2017-11-19 21:18:15", 
    "2017-11-19 21:18:26", "2017-11-19 21:18:37", "2017-11-19 21:18:48", 
    "2017-11-19 21:18:59", "2017-10-03 12:57:48")), .Names = c("id", 
"id_jornada", "id_club_home", "id_club_visitor", "home_score", 
"visitor_score", "place", "fecha", "audience", "fecha_insert"
), row.names = c(NA, 57L), class = "data.frame")
```

And that's not correct because for id_club_home we've got values distints to 10. The solution would be ...

[image]

Comment: Whenever I have a problem with for-loops I just run the code inside line-by-line, with `j` assigned to an actual value it would see, for example, until I'm sure what is happening. That's what I would do here, but it's tough without your data.

Comment: How can I run my code inside the loop line-by-line?

Comment: games$id_club_home is always numeric. The data I've got it from a query to mySQL

Comment: *"How can I run my code inside the loop line-by-line?"* Set `j <- 1`, put your cursor on the first line of the loop (`row <- teams[j,]`), hit CTRL-Enter (or whatever the hot key is to "run one line" in your editor). Then put the cursor on the next line, hit CTRL-Enter again...  Pause occasionally to make sure that the objects are what you think they are.

Comment: @Gregor, haha of course. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Going through the code one line at a time, make sure to examine little bits of lines when you find a problem. You say you have an empty subset, so `homeGames <- subset(games, id_club_home == row["idTeam"])` isn't working. What is `row["idTeam"]`? What is `class(row["idTeam])`?

Comment: Maybe you want `row[, "idTeam"]` or `row[["idTeam"]]` instead?

Comment: Please, check my post, row["idTeam"] returns 1 correctly.

Comment: Please, read my whole comment.

Comment: data.class(row) returns "function"

Comment: > print(paste(c("idTeam: ", row[,"idTeam"]), collapse = ""))
Error in row[, "idTeam"] : objeto de tipo 'closure' no es subconjunto
> print(paste(c("idTeam: ", row[["idTeam"]]), collapse = ""))
Error in row[["idTeam"]] : objeto de tipo 'closure' no es subconjunto

Comment: And `class(row["idTeam"])` is `data.frame`. You are trying to compare numerics to a one-row one-column data frame. Maybe you want `row[, "idTeam"]` or `row[["idTeam"]]` instead. `class(row[, "idTeam"])` or `class(row[["idTeam"]])` will be numeric.

Comment: It works!!! I'm sure to test it before and get a wrong result. But now, it works!!!  Thank you Gregor!!!